# Analysis of the [development-environment] tag

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, stci-phase2

> Ummm.... this question was titled with [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment). What happened?

@ThomasOwens merged [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) into [development-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment), which now needs a second pass from the community.

---

We've done a lot of great work in the cleanup of the [development-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment) (and [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)) tag, but it has become complicated enough that we need to handle the work in its own question.

The major things that need to happen are:

1. [Close, lock and/or edit the remaining open questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7451/88986)
2. [Burninate the tag from existing closed questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7452/88986)
3. [Burninate / replace the tag from closed, **locked** questions, which are obviously more complicated and require moderator involvement.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7453/88986)

Please see the answers for progress on these three separate goals.

---

For reference, also see current [tag wiki](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/development-environment/info):

> Questions about the environment in which software development happens. This includes the hardware, software, and processes and methodologies used. Questions are expected to be unique to software development and require the expertise of people with education or experience in the field of software development.

Answer (score 2):

## Burninate the tag from existing closed questions

[Search to find new questions to edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwork-environment%5D+closed%3Ayes+locked%3Ano)

Currently there are 45 closed, unlocked questions with this tag.

Answer (score 2):

## Burninate / replace the tag from closed, locked questions

See: [Tags that only exist on locked questions, should we treat these the same as tags that don't exist at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250840/tags-that-only-exist-on-locked-questions-should-we-treat-these-the-same-as-tags)

### Pending questions with multiple tags

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14706/overtime-is-part-of-the-job-true-but-a-bad-attitude?s=9|0.0000

  - Replace both [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) and [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) with [productivity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/how-many-monitors-do-you-use-why-how-they-are-used?s=11|0.0000

  - Remove [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)

### Pending questions with only one tag

- [Why do ads for s/w engineers always say they "offer a fast-paced environment"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59173/why-do-ads-for-s-w-engineers-always-say-they-offer-a-fast-paced-environment)

  - [development-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment) would be superior to [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)
  - **Needs closure**
- [Stuff every programmer needs while working](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11312/stuff-every-programmer-needs-while-working?s=5|0.0000)

  - [development-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment) would be superior to [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)
  - **Needs closure**

### Edited questions

- <strike>[How do you tell if advice from a senior developer is bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78547/how-do-you-tell-if-advice-from-a-senior-developer-is-bad)</strike>

  - Remove [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)
- <strike>[Perks for new programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106980/perks-for-new-programmers)</strike>

  - We should remove the tag, and [hiring](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring) too.
- <strike>[How can a new programmer impress the software engineer (boss)?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25432/how-can-a-new-programmer-impress-the-software-engineer-boss)</strike>

  - Both [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) and [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) need to go. Replace with [management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)
- <strike>[Is the 80 character limit still relevant in times of widescreen monitors?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/604/is-the-80-character-limit-still-relevant-in-times-of-widescreen-monitors)</strike>

  - Remove [work-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)
- <strike>[Is it "normal" for people to not work?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/is-it-normal-for-people-to-not-work?s=4|0.0000)</strike>

  - Should be tagged [productivity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity) instead
- <strike>[What is the (craziest, stupidest, silliest) thing a client/boss asked you to do?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/what-is-the-craziest-stupidest-silliest-thing-a-client-boss-asked-you-to-do)</strike>

  - I've got nothing. [team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team)? [teamwork](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamwork)? [management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)? All seem bad.

### Deleted questions

- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/what-should-i-do-when-i-cant-reach-my-deadline?s=12|0.0000</strike>
- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59740/change-managements-mind?s=13|0.0000</strike>
- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45525/open-office-arrangement-with-non-programmers-sales-etc-talking-all-day?s=15|0.0000</strike>
- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96871/my-manager-hates-documentation-in-our-large-project-what-should-i-do?s=16|0.0000</strike>
- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102348/my-lead-does-not-co-operate-may-be-lack-of-knowledge-or-unwillingness?s=17|0.0000</strike>
- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60091/programmers-and-database-professionals-in-performance-based-companies?s=18|0.0000</strike>
- <strike>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89606/working-at-home-for-a-junior-developer?s=14|0.0000</strike>