# Tag usage guidance

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions

Tl; Dr

Should I make a post in Meta to ask guidance for the usage of the tags without ***usage guidance*** that I'm considering to use in my next question before posting it?

---

Tags are part of the core elements of the Stack Exchange model. Questions should have at least one tag. Each tag has a tag wiki, showing tag stats, amogn other automatic content and two community editable parts,

- *Usage Guidance* also known as *excerpt* and usually referred as *tag excerpt*. This content is plain text and limited to 500 characters.
- *tag body*, usually referred as *tag wiki*. This content is rich text, and could be a lot longer that the *tag excerpt*

On some SE sites besides the brief usage guidance provided on the *tag excerpt*, the tag body is used to include an extended usage guidance.

---

As new user in this community, I'm a interested on learning its workings. This post is about properly use of certain tags that I have found multiple interesting for me that doesn't have *usage guidance*, some has conent in the tag excerpt but most of them don't include a extended *usage guidance* in the *tag body*.

Most of these tags have "few" questions like [application-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-design) that has 140 questions but others have a large number like [design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) that has 4,999 questions (it's the top tag).

So far I only found one tag with *usage guidance* in the wiki, [development-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment), apparently derived from the efforts around [Analysis of the [development-environment] tag](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7450/233431). I have seen that there are some Meta post labeled "Structured Tag Cleanup", created 5 years ago. Also I have seen [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) but this tag hasn't a *tag excerpt* / *tag body*.

---

This is a follow-up question derived from [Is "citizen development" on topic in Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9442/233431). The tour and some tags mentions that community members education is important on this site, I'm a self-learner of Software Engineering that have read stuff about the *unified process*, *UML*, Martin Fowler's Analysis Patterns books and some work expefience very close to this field. Based on this I took terms that I think that might be related to *Citizen Development* that might be on-topic in this site. Below there is a partial list of the tags that I have reviewed that has a tag wiki excerpt. Most of them haven't *usage guidance*.

---

Tags having "explicit" usage guidance

[design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design)

> Questions about problem solving and planning for a solution through software design.

[development-environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment)

> Questions about the environment in which software development happens. This includes the hardware, software, and processes and methodologies used. Questions are expected to be unique to software development and require the expertise of people with education or experience in the field of software development.

[development-process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-process)

> For questions relating to the process of developing software.

[enterprise-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-development)

> For questions SPECIFICALLY related to development within an enterprise environment (e.g. a large company), as opposed to e.g. hobby programming. Don't use this tag just because you're working as an enterprise developer.

---

Tags that describe the concept. Could work as usage guidance.

[application-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-design)

> Application design covers the entire pre-implementation phase of a project and consists in conceptualizing the architecture, its components, the interactions between each component, the data flows, and the processes to implement.

[cloud-computing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-computing)

> services provided on-demand and easily scale up and down

[configuration](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration)

> Configuration is an arrangement of functional units according to their nature, number, and chief characteristics.

[configuration-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration-management)

> Configuration management (CM) is a systems engineering process for establishing and maintaining consistency of a product's performance, functional and physical attributes with its requirements, design and operational information throughout its life.

[domain-model](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-model)

> A domain model is composed of the objects, behavior, relationships, and attributes that make up the industry that is the focus of development.

[enterprise-architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-architecture)

> The high level design and description of software systems frequently characterized by having large quantities of persistent data that is accessed concurrently.

[knowledge-transfer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-transfer)

> According to Wikipedia, knowledge transfer is the practical problem of transferring knowledge from one part of the organization to another.

[modeling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling)

> Creating and manipulating abstract representations of a problem or of software elements for the purpose of facilitating the understanding, reasoning, and solving of the problem.

[programming-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-practices)

> Programming Practices are the commonly or not so commonly used practices in development of software. These can include things like Agile Development, Kanban, Coding shortcuts, etc.

[solo-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-development)

> Programmers working alone, both on personal projects and on contracts.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "tag usage". If you think your question relates to the topic, then apply the tag. If you are missing a tag or used a wrong tag, I'm sure someone in the community will edit to correct.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thanks for your reply Thomas. I will follow your suggestion. P.S. The term is "usage guidance", tag was included as the usage guidance that I'm asking for is about tags. "Usage guidance" refers to instructions about when to use use a certain tag. It's Jeff Attwood, a Co-founder of Stack Exchange recommended that the most frequently used tags have *usage guidance*. This is also included in a help article.

Comment: Ref. [Tags Folksonomy and Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/01/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/), [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/), [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)

Comment: Those blog posts are over a decade old and both the blog posts and that Help Center article were written with Stack Overflow in mind. I don't know if usage guidance is needed for most tags. Since tags are supposed to give context to the question, the guidance would define the term. There may be some tags with nuances that need to be described, but those would be the minority.